# Keras model prediction changes when using tensor input

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I want to use a pretrained Inception-V3 model from Keras, paired with an input pipeline from Tensorflow (i.e. giving the network's input input via a tensor).
This is my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.preprocessing.image import load_img, img_to_array
from keras.applications.inception_v3 import InceptionV3, decode_predictions, preprocess_input
import numpy as np

img_sample_filename = 'my_image.jpg'
img = img_to_array(load_img(img_sample_filename, target_size=(299,299)))
img = preprocess_input(img)
img_tensor = tf.constant(img[None,:])

# WITH KERAS:
model = InceptionV3()
pred = model.predict(img[None,:])
pred = decode_predictions(np.asarray(pred)) #<------ correct prediction!
print(pred)

# WITH TF:
model = InceptionV3(input_tensor=img_tensor)
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
  from keras import backend as K
  K.set_session(sess)

  sess.run(init)
  pred = sess.run([model.output], feed_dict={K.learning_phase(): 0})

pred = decode_predictions(np.asarray(pred)[0])
print(pred)                               #<------ wrong prediction!
```

where `my_image.jpg` is any image I want to classify.

If I use keras' `predict` function to compute the prediction, the result is correct. If, however, I make a tensor out of the image array and feed that tensor to the model via `input_tensor=...` and then compute the prediction via `sess.run([model.output], ...)` the results are very wrong.

What is the reason of the different behaviour? Can't I use the Keras network in this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, digging through the `InceptionV3` code, I found the issue: `sess.run(init)` overwrites the weigts loaded in `InceptionV3`'s constructor.
The -dirty- fix I found to this problem is reloading the weights after the `sess.run(init)`.

```
from keras.applications.inception_v3 import get_file, WEIGHTS_PATH

with tf.Session() as sess:
  from keras import backend as K
  K.set_session(sess)

  sess.run(init)
  weights_path = get_file(
                'inception_v3_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5',
                WEIGHTS_PATH,
                cache_subdir='models',
                md5_hash='9a0d58056eeedaa3f26cb7ebd46da564')
  model.load_weights(weights_path)
  pred = sess.run([model.output], feed_dict={K.learning_phase(): 0})
```

**Note**: The parameters for `get_file()` are taken directly from `InceptionV3`'s constructor and, in my example, are specific to restoring the full network's weights with `image_data_format='channels_last'`.
I asked in [this Github issue](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/7130) if there's a better workaround for this. I'll update this answer if I should get more information.

Comment: You can always initialize a subset of variables instead of initializing every variable (including model pre-trained weights).